# Erro ao salvar regras no console do firebase

Tags: firebase, segurança, realtime-database

Quais erros podem ocorrer no console de regras de segurança do firebase realtime database ao definir minhas regras e o que são?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: syntax error

Como o próprio nome diz, são erros de sintaxe como, usar `|||` ou `&&&` em vez de `||` ou `&&`, por exemplo:

```
".write": "data.exists() &&& auth.uid == data.child('usuario').val() ||| !data.exists()
```

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: Expected

Esse erro é bem simples, como o próprio nome diz é esperado algo, um parênteses, chaves, colchetes ou vírgula, por exemplo:

```
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['nome', 'idade')
```

Falta um colchetes após `'idade'`

```
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['nome', 'idade']
```

Falta um parênteses após `'idade']`

```
"rules": 
    ".read": true
}
```

Falta abrir as chaves após `"rules":`

```
".read": true
".write": true
```

Falta uma virgula após o primeiro `true` para indicar a próxima `chave: valor`

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: Unexpected end of expression

Esse erro é causado pelas aspas das expressões, por exmplo:

```
".read": "auth.uid == data.child('usuario').val()
```

Falta de uma aspas duplas no final da expressão

```
".read": "auth.uid == data.child("usuario").val()"
```

O erro está ao usar aspas duplas dentro de outras aspas duplas, use essa apenas no início e final das expressões, e dentro delas use aspas simples

Você também deve tomar cuidado, por não estar acostumado, talvez queira fazer algo como

```
".read": "data.child("+$chave+").val() == true"
```

Mesmos variáveis (`$`) devem ficar dentro das aspas duplas

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: Rule expressions may not contain operator

Esse erro é causado ao trocar `&&` ou `||` por `&` ou `|`, não conheço outra situação que cause esse tipo de erro, por exemplo:

```
".write": "data.exists() & auth.uid == data.child('usuario').val() | !data.exists()
```

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: missing ; before statement

Esse erro é semelhante ao anterior, mas nesse caso ele ocorre quando não é usado um operador (`&&` ou `||`), por exemplo:

```
".write": "data.exists() auth.uid == data.child('usuario').val()"
```

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: Rule expressions may not contain multiple expressions

Ao ver o problema anterior você pode pensar que é simples, só colo `;` ali, mas não isso causa outro erro. Esse quer dizer que as regras de segurança não possuem suporte a múltiplas expressões (o `;` serve para isso quando usado no meio de expressões), por exemplo:

```
".write": "data.exists(); auth.uid == data.child('usuario').val()"
```

O `;` pode ser usado no **final** de expressões, porém não recomendo, além de desnecessário, é possível que esqueça que colocou e, ao adicionar uma nova condição, cause um erro nas suas rergas (meia hora procurando onde está o problema atoa), por exemplo:

```
".write": "true;"
```

Porém causa erro ao usar sem as aspas duplas, por exemplo:

```
".write": true;
```

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: Unexpected EOF

Esse erro é causado por faltar fechar alguma chave nas regras, por exemplo:

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true
```

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: Rule expressions may not contain assignments

Você não pode atribuir valores a algo (`=`) nas regras de segurança, por exemplo:

```
".read": "data.child('usuario').val() = auth.uid"
```

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: Invalid increment/decrement operand

Assim como você não pode fazer atribuições de valores a variáveis com o operador `=`, também não pode com incremento (`++`) ou decremento (`--`), por exemplo:

```
".read": "data.child('quantidade').val() == newData.child('quantidade').val()++"
```

ou

```
".read": "data.child('quantidade').val() == newData.child('quantidade').val()--"
```

Mas você pode usar os operadores de soma (`+`), subtração (`-`), multiplicação (`*`) ou divisão (`/`), por exemplo:

```
".read": "data.child('quantidade').val() == newData.child('quantidade').val() + 1"
```

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: Expression must evaluate to a boolean

ou

> Erro ao salvar regras - Linha n: left/right operand of &&/|| must be boolean

A base das regras de segurança do firebase é que elas sempre retornem verdadeiro ou falso, esses erros acontecem quando isso não acontece. A diferença entre os dois erros é que o segundo especifica aonde está o erro (a direita ou a esquerda de outra comparação), por exemplo:

```
".write": "data.exists() && data.child('usuario').val()"
```

Mesmo que `data.child('usuario').val()` seja um valor booleano você deve compar com algo, como `!= true` ou `=== true`